# libgdx: how to duplicate actors

Tags: copy, libgdx, clone, actor, tic-tac-toe

libGdx novice here. I'm making a tic-tac-toe game and I've defined an actor which is an image, one for the cross and one for the circle, I've added a event listener so that it draws the actor where I click. Now the problem is that when I try to draw the same actor on another position it moves there when it should just draw another one.

```
fieldImg.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            if(player%2!=0){
            crossImg.setPosition(Gdx.input.getX()-(fieldImg.getHeight()/3)/2, 
                                    Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY()-(fieldImg.getHeight()/3)/2);
            table.addActor(crossImg);

            }if(player%2==0){
                table.addActor(circleImg);  
                circleImg.setPosition(Gdx.input.getX()-(fieldImg.getHeight()/3)/2, 
                        Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY()-(fieldImg.getHeight()/3)/2);

            }
            player++;               
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're moving crossImg which already exists with an x, y position. You need a new actor for the new cross or circle.

```
// pseudo code
image = new Actor();
image.setX / setY
table.add(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the same `Actor` for more then one object. Instead you should use the same `Texture`. An `Actor` is not that big that you need to share it.
Also an `Actor` stores his `position`, which would be different for every of your `Actor`s.
So you should do something like this:

```
TextureAtlas textures = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.Internal("textures/atlas.pack"));
TextureRegionDrawable circle = new TextureRegionDrawable(textures.findRegion("circle"));
TextureRegionDrawable cross = textures.findRegion("cross");
```

Now you have both `TextureRegionDrawable`s. Now, when the player clicks on a cell of your TicTacToe field do the following:

```
Image actor = null;
if(currentPlayer == 1)
     actor = new Image(cross);
 else
     actor = new Image(circle);
  actor.setX(clickPos.x);
  actor.setY(clickPos.y);
  table.add(actor);
```

Note, that this is only pseudocode.
Hope it helps